# Can we prove this?

Tags: geometry

Is this true that for *any location* of $O$ (within the square) $S(ONAK)+S(OMCL)=S(OLBK)+S(OMDN)$?

P.S. The [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973122/find-the-area-of-the-shaded-region-in-the-figure-below) does not answer my question in general.

[image]

Comment: @Blue My question is general, and the referred answer does not answer the question in general. I will remove solving for concrete numbers (for ?) part.

Comment: The picture of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973149), however, does. The triangles labeled by the same letters have the same area because they have a common height and equal bases (half of the side of the square). More, it can be generalized to a rectangle or a parallelogramm.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin But how do I prove that S(a+b) = S(c+d) ?

Comment: @achillehui Is it possible prove that S(a+b) = S(c+d) ?

Comment: You don't, as $S(ONAK)=S(d)+S(c)$, $\,S(OMCL)=S(a)+S(b)$, $\,S(OLBK)=S(c)+S(b)$, $\,S(OMDN)=S(d)+S(a)$, simply compare LHS and RHS

Comment: @Alexey Burdin Thanks a lot! Now I see. I would accept both your comments as an answer!